# Sphinx "reference target not found" warning

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, django-sphinx

After creating a PR against the Django project Sphinx is emitting these warnings when running:

```
make html
```

locally:

```
/path-to-project-dir/django/docs/releases/1.10.txt:304: WARNING: py:meth reference target not found: django.test.testcases.SimpleTestCase.assertFormValid
/path-to-project-dir/django/docs/releases/1.10.txt:304: WARNING: py:meth reference target not found: django.test.testcases.SimpleTestCase.assertFormNotValid
```

Basically Sphinx is reporting it's missing references.

The error (actually a warning) also happens while building docs: http://djangoci.com/job/docs/7444/console.

Answers to a [question reporting a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10324393/1211429)  suggest editing `docs/conf.py`; however in this case this is not an option as the effect would be to edit `docs/conf.py` for the whole Django project.

Any solution to this issue that does not involve changing `docs/conf.py`?

Answer (score 1):

[Tim Graham](https://github.com/timgraham?tab=activity) replied [via github](https://github.com/django/django/pull/5595#discussion-diff-50865871) with these instructions:

> omit ".testcases" -- the documentation references use the convenience
>   import path to SimpleTestCase.

So that was the issue.